# SDWebImage does not load image from URL in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sdwebimage

In my RSS feed app, I do parsing images with NSXmlParser by entering the didStartElement method:

```
If ([element isEqualToString: @ "item"]) {
        
        Item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        Title = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        Link = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        PubDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        ImageUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    
    If ([element isEqualToString: @ "enclosure"]) {
        NSString * name = [attributeDict objectForKey: @ "url"];
        NSLog (@ "The URL is:% @", name);
        
    }
```

And in the didEndElement method:

```
If ([elementName isEqualToString: @ "item"]) {
        [Item setObject: title forKey: @ "title"];
        [Item setObject: link forKey: @ "link"];
        [Item setObject: pubDate forKey: @ "pubDate"];
        [Item setObject: imageUrl forKey: @ "url"];
        [Feeds addObject: [item copy]];
    }
```

> Ok. This works, the links I have them all.

Now I want to load these URLs into cells in my UITableView. So I used the 'SDWebImage' pod.

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method i have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];    
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"pubDate"];
    NSString *str = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"pubDate"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = str;
    NSString * string = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"url"];
    NSLog(@"THE URL IS: %@", string);

   [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.gif"]];

    return cell;

    }
```

But **nothing** happens. This is my current situation.

[image]

**How to fix?**

Comment: Could you print `string`'s value and `[NSURL URLWithString: string]` value ? The URL is probably nil

Comment: @nathan yep. I solve this problem, but now i have another problem: The images are seen but when I click on an image it changes its size and becomes longer..Why? Look http://imgur.com/YhSUiBL

Comment: nope, No I have simple pictures .jpg from url

Answer (score 0):

> sd_setImageWithURL:(nullable NSURL *)url

The API allows for nullable values so you need to check if both `string` and `[NSURL URLWithString: string]` are non-nil before using them.

Comment: yep. I solve this problem, thanks..!! but now i have another problem: The images are seen but when I click on an image it changes its size and becomes longer..Why? Look imgur.com/YhSUiBL

Comment: Post the content of `didSelectRowAt` method, and also verify if the UIImage has any IBAction/UIGestureRecognizer attached

Comment: ok, new question is online..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338779/the-width-of-images-in-uitableviewcell-changes-to-the-click