# The width of images in UITableViewCell changes to the click

Tags: ios, css, uitableview, sdwebimage

@nathan this is my entire controller.
My problem is that when I click a tableview cell, the image size is changed and becomes too long.
I can not figure out how to fix the size, I tried everything.
To do URL parsing, I used NSXMLParser, while I used SDWebImage to load images into cells.

When I press an element its size changes.
Like this:

[image]

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: You forgot to paste `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` / `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: You should probably paste the entire code of your VC if possible. Looks like you might be either modifying the selected cell's dimensions or contentMode

Comment: @nathan I wrote my entire controller

Comment: You code seems fine. You should check this question as it might be a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681273/uitableviewcell-imageview-changing-on-select

Comment: Post reply says to change the name to imageView, but I do not have a custom cell..I did not declare any image, i used cell.imageView.. how do i do it?

Comment: @nathan ok now work. the only problem is: when i open the app, the width of images is differente..how to fix? http://imgur.com/14pOKnW

Comment: That seems like a content mode issue. Set contentMode to `aspectFit`/`aspectFill`

Comment: work! please answer to the question so I'll give you the best answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like a content mode issue. Set the imageView's `contentMode` to `aspectFit`/`aspectFill` (depends on what you want to achieve)